# Android Saved Instance State Not Saving (Dual Activity)

Tags: java, android

Hi my MainActivity and MainActivity2 are supposed to be saving the instance state, but when I rotate the device into landscape it does not save the time, the timer restarts. My app is a log in verication that displays time stamps when you click the verify button, right now I am trying to save the timer when I rotate the device, but it is not saving I will include the code below thanks. Update when I comment out onRestoreInstanceState and run the program it says that I am getting a NumberFormatException in onSaveInstanceState not sure.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.security_token_app, PID: 15284
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "seconds remaining: 50"
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
        at com.example.security_token_app.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:117)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1447)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:5071)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4400)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4439)
        at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:41)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

package com.example.security_token_app;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "SharedPrefFile";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static String TIMESTAMP_KEY = "TIMESTAMP_KEY";
    private TextView countDownTextView;
    TextView passCodeTextView;
    static int passCode;
    static String currentDateTime;
    static ArrayList<String> arrayIntegerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button verifyButton;

    private static String LOG_TAG = "log state 1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        countDownTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4_time_remaining);
        passCodeTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3_passCode_int);
        verifyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

        createPassCode();
            new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000)
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long timeUntillFinished)
                {
                    countDownTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " + timeUntillFinished / 1000 % 60);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {
                    createPassCode();
                    start();
                }
            }.start();
            verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String check = sharedPreferences.getString(TIMESTAMP_KEY, null);
                    Log.i("k1","timestamp: "+check);
                    if(check != null)
                    {
                        arrayIntegerList.add(check);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "restored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    openSecondaryActivity();
                }
            });
    }
    public void createPassCode()
    {
        int minute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        passCode=minute*1245 + 10000;
        String timeStamp = getTimeStamp();
        arrayIntegerList.add(timeStamp);
        String passCodeStr = Integer.toString(passCode);
        passCodeTextView.setText(passCodeStr);
    }

    public void openSecondaryActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("timestamp_list", arrayIntegerList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static int getPassCode()
    {
        return passCode;
    }

    public static String getTimeStamp()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentDateTime;
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4_time_remaining);
    long savedData = Long.parseLong(textView.getText().toString());
    outState.putLong("outStateKey", savedData);

}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    long storedData = savedInstanceState.getLong("outStateKey");
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4_time_remaining);
    textView.setText(Long.toString(storedData));
}

}

package com.example.security_token_app;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "SharedPrefFile";
    private static String TIMESTAMP_KEY = "TIMESTAMP_KEY";
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;
    Button clearButton;
    int count;
    String item;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static boolean isSaved = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passButton);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

        ArrayList<String> timestampList = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("timestamp_list");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, timestampList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                count = adapter.getCount();
                String checkFirstPass = sharedPreferences.getString(TIMESTAMP_KEY,null);
                Log.i("k2","timestamp: "+checkFirstPass);
                if(checkFirstPass==null)
                {
                    item = adapter.getItem(count - 1);
                }
                else if(checkFirstPass!=null)
                {
                    item = adapter.getItem(count-2);
                }
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.add(item);
                saveTimeStamp(item);
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveTimeStamp(String lastItem)
    {
        if(!lastItem.isEmpty())
        {
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(TIMESTAMP_KEY, lastItem);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "time stamp saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "nothing saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_blueBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@color/sky_blue"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_passCode_string"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="PASS CODE"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="38sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_passCode_int"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_time_remaining"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:text="1:00 seconds remaining"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Verify"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />




    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height ="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_blueBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@color/sky_blue" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:dividerHeight="32dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/passButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />









    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) might help you

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel
Use ViewModel[enter link description here](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=zh_cn)

It's no problem to rotate

You can learn about the login module of Android studio
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y602T.png)

Comment: How can I implement ViewModel can you be more specific please? Thanks.

Comment: but these methods that I have written already should work though..?

Answer (score 0):

Use  [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to solve this problem

if you need a practical implementation of how to use this [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model#0)

Comment: but these methods that I have written already should work though..?

Comment: save the current value of timer  use inside of OnPause() method it may work

Comment: I can try but not exactly sure what you mean, usually people answer these questions with code and test to see if it works, thats how they gain reputation points.

Comment: I have updated the code it is getting a numberformat exception from the onsaveinstancestate method